# give external link in youtube's video

Tags: youtube, annotations, redirect

I want to add Annotation in youtube video. I found that we can do it with the associated website. But Can i give a link to any other website that is not owned by me. Let's say at the end of video i want to place a link which takes user to directly to apple store or google play store.

I found that we can first give a link to our website then from there we can redirect user to app store or anywhere else.

Is there any other way to do this without creating a redirection ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few websites that is supported without uploading a certificate and pre-approved.

List of pre-approved websites :

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2760471?hl=en